# prevent Lock Screen from showing user FullName

Tags: high-sierra, user-account, privacy, screen-lock

Is there any way to prevent the lock screen from displaying my full name?

It's a privacy matter and I would like to keep my personal data away from other people.
I know I can turn my screen off, but if someone tries to unlock my computer, she/he will be able to read my Surname.
It's also a Company machine, so I have to keep my full name in the system settings, I cannot change the name within the system.

I would only like to not show the user surname in the lockscreen.

Can it be done?

Comment: Surely people in the company know your full name anyway

Comment: @Mark - The company machine may be a laptop never used in a brick and mortar  location with Salomanuel's fellow workers!

Comment: @Mark - Or I have a Jewish surname and I work undercover in a Nazi co-working space and Apple is seriously threatening my personal security

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Terminal

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add user1 user2 user3 user4
```

Change user1 and/or user2 ect. to actual user name

If there is only one user drop the others